# Unable to use local storage in flutter web view

Tags: flutter, android-webview, flutterwebviewplugin, flutter-inappwebview

I am using `flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.0` package in my app, i am achieving every requirement of my app except I can't upload picture in my web view.
As soon as i click the icon the app crashes.
I have tried achieving this with `flutter_webview_plugin` but there are number of other issues i can't solve with that, so i decided to give inappwebview a try, but i am stil stuck at this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Android, you need to add the following codes inside the  tag of your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<provider
    android:name="com.pichillilorenzo.flutter_inappwebview.InAppWebViewFileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_inappwebview.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```